# ifstream reads different data from binary file than expected

Tags: c++

I have a problem with writing and reading byte data to and from binary file.
I am writing a data of `char*` that looks in number form like this:

> 32 16 19 23 23 84 23 16 19 23 23 84 0 0 0 0 0 0 83 8 6 1 22 21 20 0 66
>   120

But when i try to read them from the file i get this:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 48 0 0 32

Even though the amount of bytes is same, the value is completely different.

These are my functions:

```
void writeCipherTextToFile(std::string fileName, BYTE_CIPHER_TEXT cipherText) {

 std::ofstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);

 if (file.is_open()) {
      file.write(cipherText.byteArray, cipherText.count);
      file.close();
 } else {
      std::cout << "Error: Can't write file named " << fileName << std::endl;
      exit(1);
 }
}

BYTE_CIPHER_TEXT readCipherTextFromFile(std::string fileName) {

 std::ifstream file(fileName, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
 std::streampos size;
 BYTE_CIPHER_TEXT cipherText;
 char* memeblock;

 if (file.is_open()) {


      size = file.tellg();
      file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

      cout << "size: " << size<<endl;;

      memeblock = new char[size];         
      file.read(memeblock, size);

      file.close();

      cipherText.byteArray = memeblock;
      cipherText.count = size;

      delete memeblock;
 } else {
      std::cout << "Error: Can't read file named " << fileName << std::endl;
      exit(1);
 }
 return cipherText;
}
```

I have found a lot of questions about strange behavior of `ifstream` but all of these questions were character related. I don't want to get their ASCII equivalence. I want to read a raw data to `char*` so lot of values might be understood as special characters, but i don't need their meaning just their value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 48 and 32 is the decimal representation for '0' and space. That is probably a clue as to what causes the unexpected behavior.

Comment: `cipherText.byteArray = memeblock;` - are you storing a temporary here? Post an MCVE.

Comment: Yep memblock is temporary. And the strange data comes from it.

Comment: `delete memeblock;` undefined behavior, you need to use `delete[]`.

Answer (score 0):

From your use of `cipherText.byteArray` it seems to be a `char*`.

`cipherText.byteArray = memeblock;` makes it point to the same address as `memeblock`. when you then delete that buffer the `byteArray` pointer no longer points anywhere (a dangling pointer).

Reading from that pointer is undefined behavior, and will get you unpredictable results.

You should not do the delete (or `delete[]` actually) until you are done using the `byteArray`.

Comment: Unfortunately as i have written in the comments the data dump is done on memblock before the deletion.